# ASP.NET Appending Data to a ListView without refreshing entire ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, updatepanel

I've created a ListView inside an UpdatePanel that loads data without the page having to refresh. However, I need to append data one by one to the existing ListView instead of reloading the entire ListView. I realized that it's possible using the Telerik Library but I need to do it without it.

Can yall help out a bit please :)

Telerik: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/client/appendingdata/defaultcs.aspx

My Normal ASP.NET ListView:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="activityUpdatePanel" runat="server" OnLoad="activityUpdatePanel_Load" > 

          <ContentTemplate>

                  <asp:ListView ID="activityListView"  runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">

                          <LayoutTemplate>

                                  <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>

                          </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under trigger add one button and write your save code in that button and after successfull insertion  write listview bind code. inside that button only 

                       add here you button

protected void btn_save()
{
   ''     write your save code

if(saved success)
 {
  '' bind listview code here
 }
}

Comment: No mate I think you got the wrong idea. I need to add only ONE item per time to the listview and not rebind the listview everytime a new post is added